# Div Module Left and Right Margin Not Working in Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div module that displays when you click on a button. I am trying to fulfil:

- make a max-width 786px div "module" AND and Center div "module WHEN viewport is over 786px
- When viewport is under 786px, div "module" takes width 100% BUT spares 32px Left and right Margins for breathing room

I cannot accomplish the latter and I'm not sure why. The Left and Right Margin is not working as intended, except that only the Left Margin applies and pushes the div "module" off screen.

```css
.module {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 100;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: Gray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .module {
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-right: 32px;
  // I assume the value 'auto' this resets the following property
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <button>Open Module</button>
</div>

<div class="module"></div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Under 768 add `width: calc( 100% - 64px );` Why? Because width 100% + 64 margins... = what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the width:100% on you module CSS because width should change as the screen get lesser.

And remove also the line

```
/*top: auto;
 left: auto; It will just initialize your absolute position*/
```

```css
.module {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 768px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 100;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: Gray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .module {
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-right: 32px;
  /*top: auto;
  left: auto; It will just recreate 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <button>Open Module</button>
</div>

<div class="module"></div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.module {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 768px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: Gray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .module {
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-right: 32px;
  // I assume the value 'auto' this resets the following property
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
 }
}
```

and this is a link to jsfiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/LaKhDaR/auewovfr/44/